# Fetch kafka headers in spark 2.4.X

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

How to get Kafka header fields (which were introduced in Kafka 0.11+) in Spark Structured Streaming?

I see the headers implementation is added in Spark 3.0 but not in 2.4.5.
And I see by default spark-sql-kafka-0-10 is using kafka-client 2.0.

If it is not possible to read Kafka headers using Spark then can you suggest any alternative?

Comment: Looks, like spark 2.x structured streaming doesn't support kafka headers features. work around should be to use the dstreams and fetch the headers using kafkarecord.

Answer (score 0):

I don't found the way to do it in spark 2.X. can use Kafka connect SMT if the use case is simple